# how to know which table level privileges are granted to me in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I want to know which table level privileges are granted to me in oracle. how to check it?

Is there any query that displays me list of privileges which are granted to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can check it using following query :

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS_RECD;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try these below views.

```
SELECT * FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS; 
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS;
SELECT * FROM USER_ROLE_PRIVS;
```